# select data from table based on condition within same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Permissions` which consists of the following fields: `PersmissionId, UserId, DeptId, UserDefault, UserManager, UserNetwork`

The `UserDefault, UserManager, UserNetwork` values can be either `True` or `False`.

So I have the following data in the table:

`PersmissionId, UserId, DeptId, UserDefault, UserManager, UserNetwork
Row 1: 1, 1, 1, True, False, False
Row 2: 1, 1, 2, True, True, False`

Basically, I want to retrieve the DeptId of the user. So if the `UserManager` field is set to `True`, I want to retrieve it as well.

```
select 
    * from Permissions permi
    inner join Permissions permi2
on permi.UserId = permi2.UserId
where permi.UserId = 1

and permi.UBR_CH_DEFAULT = 'True' and permi.UBR_CH_MANAGER = 'True'
```

The issue is that its not returning me the two rows. Can anyone help ?

Basically, I want to check if the user is a manager or a user network. If he is any amongst these, then return me the rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the two rows, you would seem to want:

```
select p.*
from Permissions
where p.UserId = 1 and
      p.UBR_CH_DEFAULT = 'True' ;
```

If you want both rows, then you don't want the condition on the manager.

Comment: I want to check if the user is a manager or a user network. If he is any amongst these, then return me the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `OR` operator in your `JOIN` statement:

```
select 
* 
from Permissions permi
inner join Permissions permi2
      on permi.UserId = permi2.UserId OR permi.UserManager = 'true'
where permi.UserId = 1    
and permi.UBR_CH_DEFAULT = 'True' and permi.UBR_CH_MANAGER = 'True'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS and if you want one specific `userid`:

```
select p.* 
from permissions p
where 
  p.userid = 1
  and exists (
    select 1 from permissions 
    where 
      userid = p.userid 
      and (usermanager = 'True' or usernetwork = 'True') 
  )
```

If you want to check for any `userid`:

```
select p.* 
from permissions p
where exists (
    select 1 from permissions 
    where 
      userid = p.userid 
      and (usermanager = 'True' or usernetwork = 'True') 
)
```

See the [demo](https://rextester.com/ZHRAA13693).

Comment: Let's say I want to check if the value is `True` for any of `UserManager, UserNetwork`. If one of these fields is true, then return me that record. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: This is why I use `or` : `usermanager = 'True' or usernetwork = 'True'`. If one of these is true, then all the rows for this userid will be returned.

Comment: Suppose in the future, I will have more fields such `UserAdmin`, `UserDispatcher`.. Should I add `or` keyword for each column ? Aren't there any optimised way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the datatype of these columns?

Comment: The datatype is the same `varchar`. Basically, these fields represent some `access` that the user may have.

Comment: Since it is varchar then you have to use multiple `or`s. If it was `bit` it would be something easier like `col1 + col2 + ..... > 0`